# PCB Board drawing high current when little bit of liquid gets into it. How to debug the board?

Tags: voltage, pcb, current

I am new to circuit design and debugging them. I have recently helped in building a PCB with certain kind of circuits on it which includes opamp, boost converter, microcontroller and accelerometer. The board is battery operated. It basically goes on a device which is supposed to be water proofed. But by any reason the water can go inside the device.

The circuit is works fine it draws minimal sleep current in micro amps when in sleep mode and set current when its measuring. But when the liquid(approximately a drop of liquid and it would have already dried up "the liquid is mostly sugary") gets into the board "the board still works it even measures" but it starts drawing more current. Hence the battery gets drained faster.

My question is 
Can I debug the boards and bring it back to its normal working condition? If so how to debug it? 
I have 4-5 boards which are in the same condition will they all have same problem if I debug 1 board?

It would be really helpful if I could get some help from this forum.

Thanks

Comment: Distilled water is cheap in most places, and very easy to make where it is not. Wash the board with it and move on.

Comment: I agree with ignacio, wash the boards and then conformal coat them.

Comment: Thanks.I washed the board with Isopropyl alcohol. But its still drawing more current. Is it so that I need to use only distilled water?

Comment: Depending on the stuff you might want to use both liquids to clean the board, some things will solve in water and get washed away and others will solve in isopropyl alcohol. Don't use too strong solvents as they might damage your components/pcb. After cleaning make sure it has time to dry off.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the battery if it's attached to this board. Bake them for about 30 minutes at around 40C-50C (maybe check data sheets for temperature ratings but this should be okay). This should remove any moisture. Let them cool down and then perform your current consumption and functional test again.

In the future, conformal coating should help if they aren't coated. Also, maybe seal up the enclosure better with some epoxy or silicone. You could also if there's a place/room add or zip-tie a moisture absorbing packet (silica gel) to the board. Water/moisture usually finds a way even if you don't think it's possible.

Comment: If water has penetrated the packages themselves then you will need to bake for longer. See the manufacturer recommendations regarding pre-reflow baking.

Comment: Yeah, you may need to bake for longer. Use your best judgement and discretion based on the parts.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I will tryout this technique. Apparently we checked the boards and they have short. So when we finally digged in the short was found on the microcontroller which is BGA package. So seems that the liquid seeped under the BGA? And it didnt dry out. But hopefully if I bake it I can get rid of this problem too am I correct?

Comment: If you operate electronics in high humidity environments you can also develop conductive paths on the surface of the board (electrochemical migration), and even inside the board, that are difficult to get rid of.  So depending on how long they were operated with moisture, you may have developed some irreversible conductive paths.